# What does this writing mean on this jacket?

Tags: translation, characters

I saw this jacket and was wondering what the characters above the logo mean?

[image]

Comment: Please show your research attempt

Comment: I just saw [this link](https://kruzado.com/pages/summer-anarchy). It looks like it means the word "**Anarchy**"?

Comment: However, the link above states `Kanji`, so I'm not sure if it has Chinese meaning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the words 無政府. 無 means "without" or "absent of", while 政府 means "government". So literally, 無政府 means "without government". Note that this does not necessarily carry as strong of a connotation as "anarchy", although that is indeed often translated as 無政府狀態 (literally: "state of no government").

Answer (score 1):

In Chinese, it means "no government"